# How to create txt record

Tags: dkim, txt-record, ovh

I'm trying to add a secondary dns to my dedicated ovh server.

From the control panel, it says that i need to create first a txt dns record with value `xxxxx` and subdomain `ownercheck` and then continue with wizard.

I've created the txt record using `opendkim` in this way:

```
opendkim-genkey -t -s xxxxxxxx -d ownercheck.mydomain.com
```

it generates me the .key and .txt

into .txt there is something like:

```
xxxxxxxx._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=y; "
      "p=LONGKEY" )  ; ----- DKIM key xxxxxxxx for ownercheck.mydomain.com
```

I've edited this changing in:

```
"v=xxxxxxxx;p=LONGKEY"
```

and added as txt domain and i continue wizard, but unfortunately, ovh says me:

```
First we need to verify you are the owner of this domain. To do so, please add a TXT field on your DNS zone for the domain mydomain.com, with the subdomain 'ownercheck' and the following value: 'xxxxxxxx'. Once done and your zone reloaded, try again (you don't need to wait for DNS propagation).
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need dkim for these. You are supposed to add just a [TXT record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXT_record) (like `A` or `CNAME` record). It would look something like this:

`subdomain IN TXT "xxxxxxxx"`

You will need to edit your domain's nameserver zone file for this and exact procedure depneds on your provider.

Comment: I've used dkim because I used it into the configuration of a mail server. That was the first time I create a txt record. Can you please detail how can i solve? Where I can find the domain's nameserver zone file?

Comment: DKIM and SPF should be separate TXT records.  Domain ownership verification (this is your case) will require another, separate TXT record in DNS.

Comment: DKIM and SPF are actually in another TXT. but.. how can i create a txt record for this case?

Comment: @JackTurky, check at your domain registrar's control panel. Your nameservers are listed there. If it is also by ovh then check the nameserver settings there.